# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found while installing avro by Add key

Tags: gnupg, ibus-avro

I got this error message while trying to install avro software which is the most popular for wring bangla. 
I found similar answer but not found any answer related to Avro application.

I got errot message "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found"

```
wget -q http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

It held while i try to add key according to this website.
What to do to fix this problem ?

http://linux.omicronlab.com/ubuntu_14.04.html[image]

What can i do to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

First open up Terminal and run the following commands serially-

---

```
1. cd ~/Desktop

2. wget "https://github.com/ugcoder/avro/releases/download/v2.0/avro_2.0-1_all.deb"

2. sudo dpkg -i avro_2.0-1_all.deb

3. sudo apt-get install -fy (now if you see any dependency error, then also run the third command)
```

---

Avro should be installed on your system by now.

- Now go to `Settings` -> `Language Support`
- Check whether `ibus` is selected as the default input method.

From Terminal restart ibus by typing

> `ibus restart`

- Again go to `Settings` -> `Keyboard` -> `Text Entry`
- Click on the plus(`+`) Button
- Search by `Avro` name
- Click `Bengali(Avro Phonetic)` -> `Add`

Now Enjoy `Avro` as the the input source.

Answer (score 0):

The following link does not catering this. That's why it will not work.

To install avro follow the following steps

```
sudo apt install gjs gir1.2-ibus-1.0 libibus-1.0-5 libibus-1.0-dev ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-clutter ibus-qt4

wget "https://github.com/maateen/avro/releases/download/v2.1/avro_2.1-3_all.deb"

sudo dpkg -i avro_2.1-3_all.deb
```

1. Go to System Settings -> Language Support from Unity Launcher
2. Look at the Keyboard input method system
3. Select IBus and close the window.